# SQL select statement dout

Tags: sql

I have a table in which it contains the Name column contains some names in Capital letters and some data is in small letters in my WHERE clause if i give (where name='Syed') it will give only matching records because it is case sensitive but i want my output should display like(SYED,Syed,syed) how to do that please help me

Comment: `lower(column) = 'syed'`

Comment: Just use `UPPER` function `where upper(name) = ' SYED'`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name
FROM Persons
WHERE UPPER(Name) = 'SYED'
```

This will return the `Name` in whatever case it exists as in the table, but will return all instances of it.